# Macbook Pro: Yosemite crashing all the time

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, software-update

I just bought a brand new `Macbook Pro` 15 Retina Mid 2014 and it comes with `Yosemite`.

yesterday the `Contacts` app was crashing and refusing to open and giving me the following error: `Contacts quit unexpectedly` with a long description of the error.

Today the contacts problem is gone but I can't open `iTunes`, when i do it opens normally but if I tried to do anything it tells me `can't find server` even though the internet connection is perfect and working, then after few minutes it quits and tells me: `iTunes quit unexpectedly` with a long description too.

I tried to update Yosemite to 10.10.3 but it fails all the time.

What can I do ? is this normal ?

Comment: Could you please post the long description? If it won't fit into the post, please post it on GhostBin or PasteBin and put a link.

Answer (score 1):

The first two things I try when running into mysterious OSX problems is "Repair Permissions" and "Repair Disk". After that, reset your SMC and reset your PRAM. Like so...

1. In OSX, open Disk Utility (⌘ + Space and then type "Disk Utility")
2. Select your OSX partition on the left, on the right, click "**Repair Disk Permissions**"
3. When that is finished, click on "Repair Disk". If that is greyed out, select "**Verify Disk**" instead.
4. To **reset SMC**, shut down your Mac and connect it to power. While it is turned off, on the left side your keyboard press **Shift + Control + Option + Power**
5. You might not see anything happen at all. That's normal.
6. Next, **reset PRAM**. Turn on the computer and VERY QUICKLY press and HOLD **Command (⌘) + Option + P + R** (this takes two hands usually)
7. Wait until your computer does the restart ding a couple of times, and then release the keys. Let it finish booting.

At this point, any weird issues should be fixed. If you still have problems, you may need to reinstall OSX. If you still have problems after that, you have a hardware issue and need to take the computer to Apple for evaluation and repair.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a couple of things.

First create another user and log in as that user and see if any of your issues repeat. If they do then it is related to the system and not the User environment. If they do not there is likely a start up item for that user that is causing the problem.

Then reboot the Mac while holding down the shift key. When you see the gray Apple logo you may release the shift key. Boot could take a *lot* longer than normal, this is normal. Eventually the boot screen will show "**Safe Mode.**

Once booted and logged in operate the Mac and see if you can duplicate the issue. If not then there is either something that was installed or the O/S has become corrupted. See safe mode turns off all user installed things and some parts of the O/S to give you a working environment.

So if problems persist in Safe Mode, back up your stuff, boot into internet recovery mode and re-install the operating system. If it is not too inconvenient and you have a good backup and copies of anything you have installed I would reformat the HD and start fresh, just to be sure you clear any damaged/corrupted/bad files/apps.

The less fun part about now is that there may be a hardware failure. In that case make an appointment with a Genius at your local Apple store and tell them what you have already done. Be sure you back up your Mac before taking it to Apple as they could reformat the drive while troubleshooting your issue.

You may also want to post all the long descriptions of the apps crashing as it may help narrow down the issue further.